# Access IPV6 with IPV4

Tags: ipv6, nat

Sorry for my poor title.

Here is my situation：
    Our lab has a centos server  which has an local ipv4 addr  10.x.x.x and an public ipv6 addr.

I also have a ramnode server which has a public ipv4 addr and a public ipv6 addr.

And I only get an ipv4 addr at home, the question is how can I access the centos server using the ramnode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can setup an IPv6 tunnel from your home to some IPv6 tunnel broker and access the centos server on its public IPv6 address; the tunnel broker from he.net works pretty good: https://www.tunnelbroker.net/

if you would not be able to setup such a tunnel from your local machine, theres IPv4-to-IPv6 NAT too that you could do on the centos server or another middle box as described in: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ipv6/ipv6_ipv4_to_ipv6.htm