# Can I reach my ipv6 website via ipv4?

Tags: webserver, ipv6, ipv4

At my researching time, I found these relevant topics: [access ipv6 website over ipv4 network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633188/access-ipv6-website-over-ipv4-network), [Access IPV6 with IPV4 [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637407/access-ipv6-with-ipv4) and [IPv6 Webserver reachable for IPv4 only Clients](https://serverfault.com/questions/847382/ipv6-webserver-reachable-for-ipv4-only-clients).

My situation: I have a public ipv6 and a local ipv4 at home. I tried hard to forward a port, but it looks like I'm into a NAT, behind another NAT (?).
So I tried to reach my ipv6 address outside my LAN and I got success, so then I set a simple apache webserver on a raspberry pi (who has an ipv6 too) and expose it to different Dynamic DNS providers.

So, I can access these websites only in PCs that have ipv6 or ipv4 with tunneling.

The thing is, how ipv4 could reach this website? Some topics are saying that I need a proxy to "translate" ipv6-ipv4. Is it really necessary? If yes, where can I found a provider to do that?

Could someone give me some tips here? I'm pretty lost.

Comment: i think this question is more fit on [Network Engineer Stack](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It's not a professionally managed network, so network engineering wouldn't be a good fit. Superuser would be better.

Comment: OK, I can move it there. If I got the answer I post it here. Thanks!

Comment: How is this a programming question? This is a network configuration question.

Comment: Yes it is about networking. The least I could do was answer it. Moderator could exclude this question, if they want. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this question at [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1259994/can-i-reach-my-ipv6-website-via-ipv4) and I got some help from Sander Steffann, many thanks to him and to anonjnr.

There many solutions out there, one of them is to reverse-proxy your IPV4 with haproxy. Could start with this:

```
listen webserver1
    bind 192.0.2.1:80
    mode tcp
    server webserver1 2001:db8:abc:123::cafe:80
```

Or you could rent a VPS with public IPV4 (like I did) and install `socat`. This scenario its not a professional one, but works for me:

- At Raspberry IPV6 website, just set apache to listen port: 666
- At my VPS with a public IPV4, installed socat on it and ran this
  command:

`socat TCP4-LISTEN:666,fork,su=nobody TCP6:[raspberrypi_ipv6_address]:666`

So all incoming data from IPV4 port 666 will be redirected to my IPV6 port 666.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your problem. (!=/s)

If it's the port forwarding, it's in the settings of your routing equipment and we would need to know what exactly you are using to help you.

If it's a problem of ipv4 vs ipv6 the solution most of the time is to use a ddns-servie. I recommend [this service](https://www.noip.com/remote-access) as I am using it myself but there are plenty others to use. For example [this one](https://www.cloudflare.com/) as it provides not just a DDNS but a few other gadgets too.

Do you use a domain name? That would probably the easiest way to get rid of this problem.

Let me know if I got your problem right or if I failed to answer properly please. Good luck!